# why does part of the Captain America table in Pinball FX2 seem 'sticky' all the time?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

I recently bought the Captain America table for Pinball FX2. There's an area in the upper right that seems to slow the ball way down all the time-- it's where one of the Adhesive X spills is, but the effect happens even when Adhesive X isn't going. (It's also milder than the Adhesive X effect. Same kind of thing, though.)

For example, if I make the left orbit shot, so the ball is looping around to the upper right flipper, it will slow down as it approaches that flipper, which makes timing hard. And shots toward the gong-shaped target (Red Skull?) will mysteriously lose velocity, resulting in the "shoot this target harder" message.

This is all bizarre, of course, since virtual pinball games can't have sticky surfaces. But that's really how it seems.

So:

1) Is this explained by some gameplay element I don't understand? (Do I finish some round to make it go away?)

2) Am I imagining that there's an effect at all? (Is it an optical illusion?)

Comment: Actually, virtual pinball games can have sticky surfaces - not for the same reasons, obviously, but it is possible that there is something about that part of the table that slows the ball. Have you changed the view to get a better look at that area, to see if perhaps there's something else there? (I don't own the table and can't check myself.)

Answer (score 1):

I did notice this effect when I fired it up to test. The area above the top-right flipper does seem to have a slowing effect in certain cases, but it's not consistent. I think it depends where it hits. It's not an illusion, and it's got nothing to do with Adhesive X as I saw this happen before and after starting that.

You can't unfortunately flip the table around to view, so I'm unsure if there is an element there to slow down the ball. I couldn't tell you if this has changed either, as I haven't played the table in some time. I do think Pinball FX2 updated recently when I fired it up, but not sure if it changed any behavior or not.